# fragment back to the end , the screen is white

Tags: android

I have a `MainActivity`, it has a lots of `Fragment` under it.

I set the return mechanism `transaction.addToBackStack(null);`

The function like this:

```
public void switchFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.mainFrame, fragment, null);
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.commit();
}
```

My issue is when I click the back button to the end, the `FrameLayout` is white
[image: white screen]

I tried to add

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {    
        if (mainFrame==null)
            return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

It's not working. How do I avoid this white screen when I call back the `Fragment` to the end ? Any help would be great!

Comment: please show your xml file

Comment: i found solution ,thanks man.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your question what I've understood is, you have a set of `Fragment` which is launched one after one and when you press the back button, they disappears one after one. When the first `Fragment` reaches and you click the back button again, it shows a white screen.

If I'm correct, you might have to track if the first `Fragment` is reached and then finish the Activity.

Implement the `onBackPressed` function in your `MainActivity`. You might consider doing something like this.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0)
        getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    else
        finish();    // Finish the activity
}
```

Comment: Yes , you are correct ,thanks for your help , but it still shows a white screen when the first Fragment reaches

Comment: i found the way from your suggestion , i change like this 'if(getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() ==1) {
            finish();
        }'   , i avoid the white screen issue now , although i 'm not sure it's the correct solution.

Answer (score 5):

I took @ReazMushed's suggestion and changed like this:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() ==1) {
        finish();
    }else{
        super.onBackPressed()
    }
}
```

And the white screen problem is gone!